# Query dataframe index based on float value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Say I have a dataframe like this:

```
     a  b  c  d  e
index                                             
0       -202     -236      135     -178     -186
8       -139     -102      112     -100     -112
10       -77      -33       89      -22      -37
18       -16       35       62       46       26
20        45       67       36      114       90
```

And I know I can use something like `df= df.iloc[0:2]` to extract the first 3 rows of data. My question is: can I query the index based on the index value and not the index position?

For example, extract values where index=8,18 without using `df= df.iloc[1, 3]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `get_level_values`

```
df[df.index.get_level_values(0)<=10]
Out[654]: 
         a    b    c    d    e
index                         
0     -202 -236  135 -178 -186
8     -139 -102  112 -100 -112
10     -77  -33   89  -22  -37
```

If select by value, it is `loc`

```
df.loc[[8,10],:]
Out[695]: 
         a    b    c    d    e
index                         
8     -139 -102  112 -100 -112
10     -77  -33   89  -22  -37
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes!  Use `query`

```
df.query('index <= 10')

         a    b    c    d    e
index                         
0     -202 -236  135 -178 -186
8     -139 -102  112 -100 -112
10     -77  -33   89  -22  -37
```

---

If the index did not have a name, you can use `ilevel_0`

```
df.index.name = None

df.query('ilevel_0 <= 10')

      a    b    c    d    e
0  -202 -236  135 -178 -186
8  -139 -102  112 -100 -112
10  -77  -33   89  -22  -37
```

---

### Reply to Comment

```
df.query('index in [8, 18]')

         a    b    c    d    e
index                         
8     -139 -102  112 -100 -112
18     -16   35   62   46   26
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I would need something like `df.query('index == 8, 18')` and this will not work.

Answer (score 3):

You can filter by index using [`pandas.Index.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
res = df[df.index.isin([8, 18])]

print(res)

#          a    b    c    d    e
# index                         
# 8     -139 -102  112 -100 -112
# 18     -16   35   62   46   26
```

Or for a range:

```
res = df.loc[(df.index >= 0) & (df.index <= 10)]

print(res)

#          a    b    c    d    e
# index                         
# 0     -202 -236  135 -178 -186
# 8     -139 -102  112 -100 -112
# 10     -77  -33   89  -22  -37
```